# Global section of tensor product of sheaves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, sheaf-cohomology

I want to know if there is an easy proof for the following statement:

Let $X$ be a non-singular, projective variety ( maybe it is easier Surfaces=X).
Let $E$ be a locally free sheaf; then there exists an invertible sheaf $L\in Pic(X),$ such that $H^0 (X, E\otimes L)\neq 0.$

Thanks.

Comment: Look up Serre vanishing - this is exactly the result you want, and is completely general for all projective varieties.

Comment: @KReiser, I don't see the relation, because of Serre Vanishing says that $H^{i}(X, F(n))=0,$ for each $i>0.$ Not that $H^0(X, F(n))\neq 0,$ if you can explain a little about if I am going to be very thankful.

Comment: The standard statement of Serre vanishing is that for an ample line bundle $L$ on a proper scheme $X$ over a Noetherian ring $R$ and any coherent sheaf $F$ on $X$, there exists an integer $m_0$ so that for all $m\geq m_0$, $F\otimes L^{\otimes m}$ is generated by it's global sections and has zero cohomology in positive degree. If $F\otimes L^{\otimes m}$ is generated by global sections and is not the trivial sheaf, then it's $H^0$ is nontrivial.

Comment: So, Serre talk about Ampleness for $F\otimes L(n).$ Thanks a lot.